# xterm cannot load font

Tags: fonts, archlinux, xterm, wine

I'm using Arch and trying to run some exe with wine. this one I've received

```
/usr/bin/xterm: cannot load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"
```

and I've tried to install all of xorg-fonts-* that I found, but problem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running on *Arch*, [find-xterm-fonts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407710/xterm-can-not-load-font-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed-13-120-75-75-c-60-i) tells me this:

```
# opening /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
        *SimpleMenu*menuLabel.font: -adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*
        *VT100.font1:           nil2
        *VT100.font2:           5x7
        *VT100.font3:           6x10
        *VT100.font4:           7x13
        *VT100.font5:           9x15
        *VT100.font6:           10x20
        *VT100.utf8Fonts.font2: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso10646-1
        *VT100.utf8Fonts.font:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
        *VT100.utf8Fonts.font3: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-iso10646-1
        *VT100.utf8Fonts.font4: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso10646-1
        *VT100.utf8Fonts.font5: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso10646-1
        *VT100.utf8Fonts.font6: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso10646-1
        *tek4014*font2: 8x13
        *tek4014*font3: 6x13
# opening /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/UXTerm
        *VT100.font2:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso10646-1
        *VT100.font:    -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
        *VT100.font3:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-iso10646-1
        *VT100.font4:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso10646-1
        *VT100.font5:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso10646-1
        *VT100.font6:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso10646-1
# opening /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/KOI8RXTerm
        *VT100.font:    -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-koi8-r
        *VT100.font2:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-koi8-r
        *VT100.font3:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-koi8-r
        *VT100.font4:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-koi8-r
        *VT100.font5:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-koi8-r
        *VT100.font6:   -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-koi8-r

Font-files used:
        /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/helvB12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*SimpleMenu*menuLabel.font
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*VT100.font6
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        -> KOI8RXTerm*VT100.font6
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20.pcf.gz
        -> UXTerm*VT100.font6
        -> XTerm*VT100.utf8Fonts.font6
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/5x7-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*VT100.font2
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/5x8-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        -> KOI8RXTerm*VT100.font2
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/5x8.pcf.gz
        -> UXTerm*VT100.font2
        -> XTerm*VT100.utf8Fonts.font2
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*VT100.font3
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*tek4014*font3
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x13-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        -> KOI8RXTerm*VT100.font
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x13.pcf.gz
        -> UXTerm*VT100.font
        -> XTerm*VT100.utf8Fonts.font
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/7x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*VT100.font4
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/7x14-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        -> KOI8RXTerm*VT100.font3
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/7x14.pcf.gz
        -> UXTerm*VT100.font3
        -> XTerm*VT100.utf8Fonts.font3
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*tek4014*font2
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        -> KOI8RXTerm*VT100.font4
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13.pcf.gz
        -> UXTerm*VT100.font4
        -> XTerm*VT100.utf8Fonts.font4
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/9x15-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*VT100.font5
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/9x18-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        -> KOI8RXTerm*VT100.font5
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/9x18.pcf.gz
        -> UXTerm*VT100.font5
        -> XTerm*VT100.utf8Fonts.font5
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/nil2.pcf.gz
        -> XTerm*VT100.font1

No font-files missing

Packages providing font-files:

xorg-fonts-75dpi 1.0.3-4
        /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/helvB12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
xorg-fonts-misc 1.0.3-6
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/5x7-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/5x8-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/5x8.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x13-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/6x13.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/7x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/7x14-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/7x14.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/9x15-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/9x18-KOI8-R.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/9x18.pcf.gz
        /usr/share/fonts/misc/nil2.pcf.gz
```

I would suppose you're missing that package: [xorg-fonts-misc 1.0.3-6](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/xorg-fonts-misc/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late!

Go to:

> /usr/share/fonts/misc/

and check de `ISOxxx` fonts file's names there.. it could be `ISO8859`

then edit the `XTerm` config file

> /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XTerm

Change the lines where you find `iso10646` for the number you just found.

For example, change:

> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font2:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-**iso10646**-1*

To:

> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font2:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-**iso8859**-1*

You could find 5 lines to change, and get something like:

> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1*
>
> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font3:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-iso8859-1*
>
> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font4:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso8859-1*
>
> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font5:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso8859-1*
>
> **VT100.utf8Fonts.font6: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso8859-1*